# Disable Primary Key and Re-Enable After SQL Bulk Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I am about to run a massive data insert into my DB.  I have managed to work out how to enable and rebuild non-clustered indexes on my tables but I also want to disable/enable primary keys as I believe this will speed up the insertion process.

**NOTE:** This is over numerous tables and so I assume I need some loop to get the primary key information and run the following to drop it but I'm not sure about recreating it:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Table1_Col1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC clustered indexes cannot be disabled as they govern where the actual data is stored in the pages.

I'm pretty sure you would have to drop the key and re-create it after your insert.  Depending on the size of the tables, indexes and insert this may not save you any time.

Comment: I was under the impression that disabling indexes before huge inserts and reenabling them afterwards would be a better process

Comment: Yes for nonclustered indexes I believe it is.  But by dropping and recreating a clustered index it may not be so beneficial.  recreating the clustered index will then reorganise all of the data at page level?

Comment: With a clustered index the data is actually stored inside of the index, so dropping the index is actually deleting the table.

Thus dropping a clustered index means creating a new table without the index and copying all the data to this new table, then deleting the original and renaming the new. Quite a process.

Answer (score 4):

```
Run This :
//For disable all constraint of your all tables
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
//Your insert query here ......................
//After Insert Enable all the constraint
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
```